# Docker Alernatives For Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, orchestration, container-runtime-interface

According to what I read from [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.20.md#deprecation), Docker support is deprecated and removed in future version of kubernetes. Do you guys know why and how can you handle it?

Comment: The [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) lists two alternatives to docker: [cri-o](https://cri-o.io/) and [containerd](https://containerd.io/).

Comment: Recommendations are off topic here, but note https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/